# MYSQL GROUP BY MAX score

Tags: mysql

I have a table called scores which contains columns

[image]

How do I select which id_team is top scorer per game

i m trying with this, but that's not correct result

```
SELECT MAX( score ) , id_team
FROM scores
GROUP BY  `id_game` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self join to find out the right team id for game a which has max score

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM scores s
JOIN (
SELECT MAX(score) score, id_game 
FROM scores
GROUP BY id_game ) ss USING(score ,id_game )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.id_game, A.id_team as winning_team
from scores A,
(
select max(score) as max, id_game
from scores
group by id_game
)B
where A.id_game = B.id_game
and A.score = B.max
```

Comment: `select A.id_game, A.id_team as winning_team
from scores A,
(
select max(score) as max,id_game
from scores
group by id_game
)B
where A.id_game = B.id_game
and A.score = B.max`