# MySQL select max for each user_id and also get some other field

Tags: mysql

Assume we have a table:

```
+----+---------+-------+--------+
| id | user_id | score | errors |
+----+---------+-------+--------+
| 1  | 123     | 50    | 12     |
| 2  | 123     | 55    | 7      |
| 3  | 444     | 90    | 1      |
| 4  | 555     | 78    | 2      |
| 5  | 123     | 50    | 0      |
+----+---------+-------+--------+
```

How can I select 3 users with MAX score and errors for these MAX scores?
I expect to get ids:
3, 4 and 5

P.S. I use MySql with only_full_group_by enabled

UPDATE: I have to get MAX score for each user and also the exact field errors (which is related to the MAX score of this user)

ANSWER: 
It might be simply done using the following query. But in case when one user has two same MAX scores (like user 123 has 2 records with score = 50) it would return 2 records for the user. And here we can just leave the last record (e.g. index by user_id using PHP or some other language)

```
SELECT t1.user_id, max_score, errors
FROM tbl t1 JOIN (
    SELECT max(score) AS max_score, user_id
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.score = t2.max_score;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL GROUP BY MAX score](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23192153/3340665)

Comment: Is score the same thing as MAX score or can a user have two rows in the table with different scores? What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: I you want the top three scores, I would expect you to get id 3, 4 and **2**.

Answer (score 1):

To get 3, 4, 5, you don't need aggregation function and order by.

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id, user_id, score, errors
from my_table

order by score desc, errors desc limit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an another perspective. First give a rank/row_number for each `user_id` based on their score in descending order. Then we can select the rows with rank/row_number having the value 1.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.score, t.errors FROM(
    SELECT id, user_id, score, errors, 
    (
        CASE user_id WHEN @curA 
        THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curA := user_id END 
    ) AS rn 
    FROM tblScore t, 
    (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    ORDER BY user_id, score DESC
)t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.score DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2610e/1)

Comment: This query works fine. I also provided some other way to do it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Order by descending order and get first 3 records:

```
Select id, user_id,score, errors FROM [Table_Name] order by score desc, 
errors asc limit 3
```